# Builder pattern vs. Dependency Injection (for instance via Guice)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm developing a simple tree-structured database and I'm usually setting dependencies or optional settings via a Builder (Builder pattern). Now I'm not sure when to use for instance Guice, when to use the Builder pattern and when to use a static factory method instead of the constructor itself. I've read Effective Java several times and I think it mentions at least a lot of advantages for not exposing the constructor. It's time to reread ;-)

So, do you know of cases which are clearly distinguishable? And shouldn't I expose the constructor? Thus for instance in every case write `public static Foo getInstance(...) { return new Foo(...)}`?

Comment: I suggest do what you believe is the simplest and most natural way of building your components.

Comment: Always strive to create regular Java objects, with constructors or setters. Then, on some special occasions, consider `DI` to decouple implementations, or `factories`/`builders` to assist your constructional logic *when* **needed**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm a firm believer in that you don't need to use dependency injection for *everything*.

- For a `LookupService` it would be natural **inject** a `Dictionary` such that its implementation can be swapped out by configuration.
- For a `Firewall` on the other hand. It would be natural for it to create its own `FireWallRules`, perhaps through a supplied `Factory` or a `Builder`.

As a guideline, inject what you need to *configure*, don't automatically inject everything else.

---

Consider a **`static factory (*)`** when

- named construction logic is desired. E.g., `Lists.newArrayList()`
- the construction is so complicated it doesn't belong in the class itself
- no configuration of the factory is required, and the factory has **no** side effects

Consider **`instance factories`** when

- there is complex instantiation logic
- configuration of the factory is needed
- using `AbstractFactory` design pattern
- there's need to create additional objects throughout the programs lifecycle

Consider a **`builder`** when

- there are complex parameter choices. E.g., 5 parameters where some are optional.

---

**`(*)`** *Static methods are not always testable and the presence of one should in my opinion always be motivated*. 
A typical usecase for a factory is to decrease **coupling**. By using a `static factory` that ability is completely lost.

Comment: So maybe instead of using the AbstractFactory design pattern dependency injection frameworks are sometimes used?

Comment: @Johannes, In a *sence*. A `Factory` is *primarily* needed to create additional instances through the programs lifecycle. A `Factory` can *still* be injected by a framework through.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg I find myself actually relying more on injected Factories when I use D.I.

Comment: Just a small point: In your example of a `FireWallRules`, there actually is an advantage to DI, since you can use a different implementation in order to automatically save them to a file and reload them automatically, for instance. For things like that, I usually use an instance factory.

Answer (score 13):

> Builder pattern vs. Dependency Injection

How are these 2 *even close* to comparable in your mind?
The **builder pattern** is used when you need to deal with classes whose constructors would have an overwhelming number of parameters (potentially optional) and this pattern makes your code easier to read and write.

**Dependency Injection** is an approach that facilitates loose coupling removing the dependencies of higher level classes to lower level classes. E.g. a class that needs to connect to a database does not directly create a connection but a connection is "injected" and this connection could be swapped to a different database without affecting the code using it.

Comment: Is it possible to use builder pattern and Assisted Injection together on an object creation?

Answer (score 3):

I have started using builder for most of my projects and it turns out I can and have replaced all of my DI with builders and singleton.

ie:

```
AppContext appContext = new AppContext.Builder()
.setProperties(testProps)
.setDB(testDB)
.build();

// run tests
```

My code has become much simpler to manage without DI.

Comment: what if you want to change AppContext?