# What is the difference between dependency injection container and builder design patterns

Tags: php

friends i am studing about DIC, I understand that it is injecting the required dependency to the object. And i also know about the 'bulider design patterns' which are also doing the same thing. What is the difference between these two methodolgy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Builder pattern vs. Dependency Injection (for instance via Guice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520678/builder-pattern-vs-dependency-injection-for-instance-via-guice)

Comment: They are two different things. Builder is a creational design pattern and dependency injection is an inversion of control technique. You should read and compare Constructor, Builder, Setter and Factory creational patters and learn about IoC separately.